# Issue installing Midori

Tags: midori

I've downloaded Midori, and am attempting to build and install. According to the install instructions, I need to do this:

> Make sure you have Python 2.4 or higher installed.
>
> Change to the Midori folder on your
>   hard disk in a terminal.
>
> Run './waf configure'
>
> Run './waf build'
>
> You can now run Midori from the build
>   folder like so
>
> './waf build --run'
>
> Using --run as shown above will make
>   sure extensions as well as
>   localizations are used from the build
>   folder.
>
> You can install it with './waf
>   install'

When I run configure, though, I get the following:

```
esther@esther-linux:~/midori-0.3.6$ ./waf configure
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for program valac               : not found 
Vala is required for some extensions. 
Pass --disable-vala to not build with Vala.
```

The instructions don't mention anything about Vala; what is it and where can I get it?

Comment: Would you like the Midori-dev ppa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a programming language that gets compiled into C (see Wikipedia). This is the first time I've seen it being used - cool :)

If you install valac from synaptic or the Software Centre you should get past that check.

Answer (score 1):

go to software center, type in midori and install. comes as a default in some distros.  also comes with duckduckgo search engine.  one of the most secure i have used.  not an advert, just my opinion.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. For some reason it never occurred to me it would be in the software center.